# How to navigate the command line in mysql?

Tags: mysql, vim, command-line, editing

I wanted to be able to up-arrow and change stuff in my last command.
I'd like to be able to use vim bindings the way I can at the terminal command with `set -o vi`

Is there anyway I can set that up for mysql?
I know that I can use edit and then edit it in vim.  This is handy but unfortunately is not playing well with then just using up-arrow in `mysql>` as it bring back the last command but not the last edited command.

I just discovered `ctrl-a` will go the start of the line.  Failing vim key-bindings is there a list of other control keys that I can use to navigate the `sql>` command line?

Comment: `$ man mysql`, followed by `/Editing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If vim bindings aren't an option I have found the following useful:

```
ctrl-a start of line
ctrl-e end-of-line
ctrl-k delete to end of line (‘kill line’)
```